# BEBK G-13 mouse automatically start pasting data from clipboard

Tags: windows-10, mouse, copy-paste, clipboard, ctrl

**Mouse:**
BEBK G-13 mouse, This is a mouse with 6 buttons + joystick as well under the thumb...

**Issue:**
Mouse Suddenly start pasting the data from clipboard into any open windows in an infinite loop.

**Resolution (so far):**
Disconnect mouse cable, logout and login again...

**Other Findings:**
I have notices that CTRL key of keyboard is also shown as pressed when mouse start mal-functioning...

**Methods tried:**
I have searched google for the mouse software but couldn't find...
Tried generic mouse customization software "X-Mouse Button Control" but still issue is not resolved...

***My system:***
Dell Optiplex 9020
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz
Installed RAM   12.0 GB

***OS:***
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎1/‎25/‎2021
OS build    19042.928
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: Try another mouse.

Comment: @harrymc another mouse works fine, but I want to resolve the issue of this mouse...

Comment: A bad mouse cannot be fixed (or isn't worth the cost). The most one can do is clean it up as much as possible.